# Gerrit duplicate request rejected

Tags: git, gerrit

I modified some files, made a new commit, and then typed `git pull` 
Then git automatically made a new merge commit that was empty!
So then I did a `git rebase` to try to get rid of it.
And the empty commit is now gone.

But now when I do `git review`, I get

```
You are about to submit multiple commits. This is expected if you are
submitting a commit that is dependent on one or more in-review
commits. Otherwise you should consider squashing your changes into one
commit before submitting.

The outstanding commits are:

←[33me4b3f96←[m←[33m (←[m←[1;36mHEAD←[m←[33m -> ←[m←[1;32mmaster←[m←[33m)←[m unit tester fixes
←[33mbc61468←[m Addded test cases to ...
←[33me21d8c7←[m Added test cases to the 
←[33ma8d2919←[m added another test case
←[33m938ef4f←[m Modified a few tests
←[33mbee5ba1←[m FA initial

Do you really want to submit the above commits?
Type 'yes' to confirm, other to cancel: yes
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (38/38)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote: (W) bc61468: commit subject >65 characters; use shorter first paragraph
remote: (W) bc61468: commit message lines >70 characters; manually wrap lines
To ssh://jkl@review-thing.bo.com:29418/IM
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master (duplicate request)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://jkl@review-thing.bo.com:29418/IM'
```

How do I figure out why it says duplicate request? I don't understand why that's happening. I've tried various things to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind.
So my commit "added another test case" had the same change ID as commit "Modified a few tests". I had made the change ID the same so that it would appear as a patch set under the previous commit on gerrit. 
But it seems like gerrit wants you to squash the changes instead into one commit.

So I squashed them and now I don't get duplicate errors.